# Powering a pressure transducer

Tags: power-supply, power, current, pressure

I am new to building testing setups.  I have an Omega PX603-30VAC5V pressure transducer that I need to power.  I have a Rhino Power Supply PSP24-060C that is listed as 24VDC/2.5, the pressure transducer is powered by 24VDC excitation with a supply current of less than 3mA.   I think my power supply current is too high.

[image]

Comment: think about this ... a power outlet at your house can provide enough current to run a hair drier ... why does it not burn up a night light?

Comment: this has been asked and answered innumerable times here ... a voltage of 24 V is only able to push 3 mA through the transducer ... you would have to raise the voltage to push more current

Answer (score 1):

Your [PX603 or PX613 pressure sensor](https://assets.omega.com/pdf/test-and-measurement-equipment/pressure/pressure-transducers/PX603.pdf) can operate with an excitation voltage of 10 to 36 volts.  Your 25V power supply is fine.

The sensor will only take the current it needs from the power supply.  That's the 3 milliamperes mentioned in the datasheet.  It doesn't matter if your power supply can deliver just 3 mA, or if it can deliver 50A.  The sensor will only draw a maximum of 3mA when operated on its rated voltage.

Voltage and current rating from the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  That is what I thought, it has just been awhile and I am not good about trusting myself when money is at stake!   Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is determined by the powersupply, while the current is determined by the load.  You just need to find a supply that is the correct voltage and **can supply at least enough current for the load**.

Powersupplies like this don't "push" current.  They provide a *voltage* **up to** a certain current.

Using [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) you can see that the resistance of the load, combined with the voltage of the supply determine the current through the circuit.

Comment: Thanks for the reassurance and the reminders about Ohm's law.  It is been awhile but I the schooling is starting to come back.   Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

There are power supplies requiring a certain minimum load current, some PC power supplies for instance.

But the datasheet https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/rhinopsp.pdf contains no remark about a minimum load current.

So any load current between 0 and 50 % is possible, even in a hot environment. See the specs about derating.